# TeeChart: How to bring a series to the front

Tags: c++builder, teechart

IDE: `c++ Builder XE5 Update 2`

TeeChart Build: `2014.11.140512`

I am trying to bring certain series on a `TChart` component to the front(as you would typically do with a `BringToFront()` function).

I've done some reading and found the following options/suggestions:

A. Change the `ZOrder` property of the series.

B. Use `TChart.ExchangeSeries()`

Using `TChart.ExchangeSeries()` is not a proper way of changing the z-order of a series. Its primary function is to swap around two series in a `TChart` component's `SeriesList`(which then inherently changes the z-order of those series). If you require your series-ordering to be fixed(fixed ordering in `SeriesList`), then this will not work.

Changing the `ZOrder` properties of the series delivered better results. However, changing the `ZOrder` of the first series(`Series[0]`) apparently does nothing. `Series[0]` seem to like sitting at the back of the class.

The above might be the result of my implementation. In which case, some more details:

On my `TChart` component I have multiple series. The series-types can be changed dynamically. The types to which the series can be changed are limited to `TLineSeries` and `TBarSeries`.

**I always want the `TLineSeries` at the front**.

Any advice on how this can be done?

(Will we ever see that elusive `TChartSeries.BringToFront()` function?) :)

Answer (score 0):

> Any advice on how this can be done?

Looks like mixing series styles and changing ZOrder is not working very well. For example, using this code snippet:

```
uses Series;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries.Create(Self)).FillSampleValues(10);
  Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries.Create(Self)).FillSampleValues(10);
  Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries.Create(Self)).FillSampleValues(10);
  Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries.Create(Self)).FillSampleValues(10);
  Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries.Create(Self)).FillSampleValues(10);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  for i:=0 to Chart1.SeriesCount-1 do
  begin
    Chart1[i].Marks.Visible:=False;

    if Chart1[i] is TLineSeries then
      Chart1[i].ZOrder:=Chart1.SeriesCount - 1 - i
    else
      Chart1[i].ZOrder:=i;
  end;
end;
```

Line series are brought to the front but bar series style remain there. I have also tried with bar series StackGroups: However, it doesn't make much of a difference. We'd need StackGroups for line series as well for this work.

> (Will we ever see that elusive TChartSeries.BringToFront() function?)
>   :)

Why not? I have added your request to Steema Software's bugzilla platform: http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=853. Feel free to sign up and add yourself to the CC List to receive automatic issue updates.

Comment: Thanks for adding the request! Luckily, at present and due to the nature of the project and the initial manner in which it will be used, I should be able to avoid the issue for the time being(by not changing `Series[0]` to a `TLineSeries`; line-series at higher indices seem to work).